# Java Casting Interface to Class

Tags: java, casting

```
public class InterfaceCasting {

    private static class A{}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        Serializable serializable = new Serializable(){};
        a = (A)serializable;
    }

}
```

Compilation succeed but Runtime exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: InterfaceCasting$1 cannot be cast to InterfaceCasting$A
```

WHY COMPILATION SUCCEED? Compiler must known that serialiazable is not A?

Comment: i think you have to review concepts on Java Exception...

Answer (score 28):

As you point out, this *will* compile:

```
interface MyInterface {}

class A {}

public class InterfaceCasting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInterface myObject = new MyInterface() {};
        A a = (A) myObject;
    }
}
```

**This** however, will *not* compile:

```
interface MyInterface {}

class A {}

public class InterfaceCasting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = (A) new MyInterface() {}; // javac says: "inconvertible types!"
    }
}
```

So, what's going on here? What's the difference?

Well, since `MyInterface` is simply an interface, **it *could* very well be implemented by a class that extends A**, in which case the cast from `MyInterface` to `A` would be legal.

---

This code for instance, will **succeed in 50% of all executions**, and illustrates that the compiler would need to solve possibly undecidable problems in order to always "detect" illegal casts at compile time.

```
interface MyInterface {}

class A {}

class B extends A implements MyInterface {}

public class InterfaceCasting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInterface myObject = new MyInterface() {};
        if (java.lang.Math.random() > 0.5)
            myObject = new B();
        A a = (A) myObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this also possible without extending A ? Because that is what I need.

Comment: How do you even instantiate an interface like new MyInterface(){};? This makes no sense.

Comment: @The_Martian, the `{}` in the end of the line creates an anonymous class implementing the interface. Try it! :-)

Answer (score 10):

[Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.5) states, that:

> Some casts can be proven incorrect at compile time; such casts result in a compile-time error.

And later on the show *The detailed rules for compile-time legality of a casting conversion of a value of compile-time reference type S to a compile-time reference type T* - beware, they are very complex and hard to understand.

The interesting rule is:

- If **S** is an **interface** type:

  - If **T** is a type that is **not final** (§8.1.1), then if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs. **Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if T does not implement S, a subclass of T might)**.

In your example, it's perfectly clear, that the cast is illegal. But consider this slight change:

```
public class InterfaceCasting {

    private static class A{}
    private static class B extends A implements Serializable{}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        Serializable serializable = new B(){};
        a = (A)serializable;
    }    
}
```

Now a cast from a `Serializable` to `A` is possible at runtime and this shows, that in those cases, it's better left to the runtime to decide if we can cast or not.

Comment: yeah , I got it now
Thanks everybody for your help

Answer (score 4):

```
Serializable serializable;
a = (A)serializable;
```

As for the compiler, the variable serializable can contain any object that implements `Serializable`, which includes subclasses of `A`. So it assumes that you know that the variables indeed contains an `A` object and allows that line.

Comment: No, it may **not** include `A`. The compiler knows for sure that `A` doesn't implement `Serializable`.

Comment: @aioobe yes, but a subclass of `A` may

Comment: you should clarify this by writing "which includes subclasses of A".

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not smart enough to trace the origins of `serializable` and realize that it can never be of type `A`. It really only evaluates the line:

```
a = (A)serializable;
```

and sees that `serializable` a reference of type `Serializable` but it may reference a class that **also** is of type `A`. The actual class that `serializable` references is not known until run-time.

In this trivial case, we know that this cast will never succeed, but in general this is left as a run-time issue as the different code paths that may lead to a casting are (in theory) infinite.

If you want to avoid this issue at run-time you could test for it..

```
if (serializable instanceof A) {
    a = (A)serializable;
} else ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't know that because the compile time type of `serializable` is `Serializable`.

To illustrate, consider this:

```
private static class A{}
private static class B implements Serializable {}

Serializable serializable = new B();
A a = (A)serializable;
```

this is exactly like your question, it compiles.

```
private static class A{}
private static class B implements Serializable {}

B b = new B();
A a = (A)b;
```

this does not compile because `b` is not an `A`.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the correct answer, it's usually not a good idea to cast an interface to a class, for several reasons.

a) An interface defines a contract, it guarantees behavior. A class may define more than this contract, usage of the other methods may have unexpected side-effects and break APIs. E.g. when a method is passed a list and you find out the passed object is actually a LinkedList and you cast it and use the Queue based methods it also defines, you are breaking the API.

b) also, the object with the interface may not be a "real" object at runtime, but perhaps a service proxy created around the original object by a library such as Spring or EJB. Your cast will fail in those cases.

If you absolutely must cast, never do it without an instanceof check:

```
if(myServiceObject instanceof MyServiceObjectImpl){
    MyServiceObjectImpl impl = (MyServiceObjectImpl) myServiceObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The detailed rules for compile-time legality of a casting conversion of a value of compile-time reference type S to a compile-time reference type T are as follows:
>   [...]
>   If S is an interface type:
>   - If T is an array type, [...].
>   - If T is a type that is not final (§8.1.1), then if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs. Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time **(because even if T does not implement S, a subclass of T might)**.

**Source :**
[JLS : Conversions and Promotions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#184308)

Answer (score -1):

`Serializable` is NOT an `A`, so it throws `ClassCastException`.